# SHELL update date column in file to timestamp

Tags: shell, unit-testing

With an input:

```
1,aaaa,2018-11-03
2,bbbb,2018-02-03
```

Expected output

Script should treat date as MST7MDT format and convert it to UTC:

```
1,aaaa,2018-11-03 06:00:00
2,bbbb,2018-02-03 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your OS. Assuming you have GNU date:

```
(
    IFS=,
    while read -ra fields; do 
        t=$(TZ=America/Denver date -d "${fields[-1]}" "+%s")
        fields[-1]=$(TZ=UTC date -d "@$t" "+%F %T")
        echo "${fields[*]}"
    done
) <<END
1,aaaa,2018-11-03
2,bbbb,2018-02-03
END
```

```
1,aaaa,2018-11-03 06:00:00
2,bbbb,2018-02-03 07:00:00
```

I like Perl's `DateTime` library ecosystem:

```
perl -E '
    use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
    my $dateparser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern   => "%Y-%m-%d",
        time_zone => "America/Denver"
    );
    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /,/;
        my $datetime = $dateparser->parse_datetime( $fields[-1] );
        $fields[-1] = $datetime->set_time_zone("UTC")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T");
        say join ",", @fields;
    }
' <<END
1,aaaa,2018-11-03
2,bbbb,2018-02-03
END
```

Comment: file=myfile
while IFS= read -r line
do
     CSID=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,)
     mt=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d,)
  echo $mt   
     t=$(date -u -d 'TZ="MST7MDT" $mt' "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
     echo $CSID,$t >> fWithTZ.dat  
done < $file

Comment: Nice job with one call to date. Better way to read into fields: `while IFS=, read -r csid f2 mt rest; do...` Don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: it's too easy to overwrite crucial shell variables like PATH

Comment: Worked fine with below code #!/bin/bash

file=myfile 
while IFS= read -r line 
 do csid=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,) 
 name=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,)
 oldmt=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d,) 
 echo "$csid"",""$name"","$(date -u -d "TZ=\"MST7MDT\" $oldmt" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> newmyfile.dat 
done < $file

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine with below code

```
#!/bin/bash 
file=myfile 
while IFS= read -r line 
do 
csid=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,) 
name=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,) 
oldmt=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d,) 
echo "$csid"",""$name"","$(date -u -d "TZ=\"MST7MDT\" $oldmt" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> newmyfile.dat    done < $file
```